# tables relation in database redundant

Tags: database

i have one product table 
which have

product_id name price

and i want to store multiple images of single product here product_id is primary key and auto increment so how would store i store multiple images of single product.

one solution is define anothe table which has product_id as a foreign key

that is

product_id images

suppose i add

product_name moblie it id is auto incerment.....so how would i store the multiple images of this as i does not know what product_id is genertaed as it is auto increment?????

please help anyone????

Comment: Store the product record, get the generated ID, store the image records.  What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Create a second table with a generated id, product_id (foreign key) and image_location or something.

Then you're there.

Comment: yeah but how i find generated id ??? because the field product_id is auto incremented..